# How to draw in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am very noob in Photoshop. I want to draw a tree with leaves, just to practice following the original psd file. But no way I can achieve the same level of excellency the original one has. I tried both pen tool (shape) and Brush tool. Neither way works.

And also the layer indicated that (from original file) that the tree has been drawn as one shape layer! How can someone draw that?

Please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Work like this is better done in vector image editing software, such as Illustrator, Inkscape, CorelDraw, Figma, etc.

Comment: @BillyKerr You are right.  I drew it in Illustrator then copy paste in Photoshop. Photoshop hates me. The feeling is mutual  -_-

Comment: Instead of copy pasting, save the AI file, and then drag the file into a Photoshop document. It will be placed as a Smart Object, and will remain vector. If you double click the Smart Object, it will open in Illustrator for editing.

Comment: Thank you.  I will do that.

Comment: programs do not hate anyone. But they cannot guess what the user wants, they only do what one asks. Here's a cartoon how to draw a leaf in a far from fast and optimal way in Illustrator without the pen  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWx1a.png The pen starts to obey your will if you practice few days by working some  tutorials and drawing things. Understanding paths and the pen is essential to be productive in Illustrator.

Comment: You can paste as a smart object as well. No need to save the ai file and drag it.

Comment: @user287001 Thank you. I was questioning my merit :'( , how come I can not draw a simple tree with some laves. This really helps. <3

Comment: @Scott Okay . I learn so many things from you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often draw little bits like this in **Illustrator**, then copy/paste as *paths*, or shape layers, to Photoshop where I can do the raster stuff. I don't even keep them as Smart Objects much of the time if the coloring is simple enough.

Photoshop's Pen Tool is fine - but things fail in the path interactions, anchor aligning, joints, etc. That sort of stuff is just cumbersome in Photoshop.

But this simple leaf should be easily accomplished with Photoshop's Pen Tool set to shapes. It merely takes practice to know how curves will be laid down and where the best place for anchors may be. Which is the same as in Illustrator. There's rarely a need to draw at an angle if you can merely rotate something a*after* it's drawn. Often creating things on perpendiculars is helpful.

[image]

<sup>Animation is sped up to create a smaller file</sup>

[image]

Then I'd merge Shapes from the Layer Panel menu... adjust the center line a bit more.... and I've have a leaf in a single, editable, layer which I can then duplicate, rotate, and scale to create the other leaves.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I could draw now. I am happy.